# Jquery drag and drop with Table Cells and getting their position to save

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

here i have the following html, as it is basically match the following concept, i need to able drag and drop the AnswerSide Cells.  Only Answers Side cells can me moved up and down. and after moving, we need to get the Text of the answer and its position.   (as i am doing in asp.net, and the table will be genrated behind the code.)

1. User can move up and down the Answers. (**only Answers can be moved**)
2. We need to retrive the text, and its position
3. We need to save it in DB

can any one tell me how to do this. i tried [Jquery Ui sortables](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable), as i am not getting it. as i am beginner, can anybody help me to solve the problem.

**I updated with HtmlTable, and  Div Layout, however now any one can help me to solve, in either way**

[JSFIDDLE Link for Following HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/dYUJQ/)

[Jsfiddle for Div Layout](http://jsfiddle.net/NAHjy/)

```
<html>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>QuestionSide</td>
        <td>Answer Side</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 1  </td>
            <td><div> Ans1 </div> </td> // this div is needed to 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>question 2 </td>
            <td><div > Ans2  </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> question 3</td>
            <td><div> Ans3  </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> question 4</td>
            <td><div> Ans4  </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> question 5 </td>
            <td><div> Ans5  </div> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, stop using tables for layouts !! It is not 1999 anymore.

Comment: ok, if possible can you show me in div'also, with same layout

Comment: @tereško i updated with Div Lay out, can you help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. I agree with @tereško You should use divs. But even then, you will be faced with the same issues. You could just put a sortable next to another set of divs, but a sortable may not work for you especially if the answer rows need to match the height of the question rows.

Here is the code that you need to drag and drop answers.
HTML:

```
<table border="1" id="qatable">
<tr>
    <td>QuestionSide</td>
    <td>Answer Side</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Question 1  </td>
        <td><div class="answer answer1"> Ans1 </div> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>question 2 </td>
        <td><div class="answer answer2"> Ans2  </div> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> question 3</td>
        <td><div class="answer answer3"> Ans3  </div> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> question 4</td>
        <td><div class="answer answer4"> Ans4  </div> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> question 5 </td>
        <td><div class="answer answer5"> Ans5  </div> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
<button onclick="alert($('.answer').index($('.answer1'))+1);">Get position of answer 1</button><br />
<button onclick="alert($('.answer').index($('.answer2'))+1);">Get position of answer 2</button><br />
<button onclick="alert($('.answer').index($('.answer3'))+1);">Get position of answer 3</button><br />
<button onclick="alert($('.answer').index($('.answer4'))+1);">Get position of answer 4</button><br />
<button onclick="alert($('.answer').index($('.answer5'))+1);">Get position of answer 5</button><br />
<br /><br>
<button onclick="alert($('.answer').eq(0).html());">Get answer of question 1</button><br />
<button onclick="alert($('.answer').eq(1).html());">Get answer of question 2</button><br />
<button onclick="alert($('.answer').eq(2).html());">Get answer of question 3</button><br />
<button onclick="alert($('.answer').eq(3).html());">Get answer of question 4</button><br />
<button onclick="alert($('.answer').eq(4).html());">Get answer of question 5</button><br />
```

And here is the jQuery code. Make sure you have included the jquery and jquery ui script files.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.answer').draggable({
        axis: 'y',
        opacity: 0.5,
        containment: $('#qatable'),
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 0,
        distance: 10,
        cursor: 'pointer'
    }).droppable({
        accept: '.answer',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            ui.droppable = $(this);
            var answers = $('#qatable').find('.answer');
            toindex = answers.index(ui.droppable);
            fromindex = answers.index(ui.draggable);
            var placeholder = $('<div id="placeholder">&nbsp;</div>').insertBefore(ui.droppable); // Placeholder
            if (toindex < fromindex) { // Moving an answer up
                for (var i=toindex;i<fromindex;i++) { 
                    answers.eq(i).insertBefore(answers.eq(i+1)); // Shift everything down
                }
                ui.draggable.insertBefore(placeholder); // Move the draggable answer to where the other one was
                placeholder.remove();
            } else { // Moving the answer down
                for (var i=toindex;i>fromindex;i--) { 
                    answers.eq(i).insertBefore(answers.eq(i-1)); // Shift everything up
                }
                ui.draggable.insertBefore(placeholder); // Move the draggable answer to where the other one was
                placeholder.remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Whether you actually use divs or table cells, is irrelevant. The code still works in either divs or table cells. All you need to do after that is style the table cells.

To get the position of an answer, just use the index method.

```
var pos = $('.answer').index($('.answer1'))+1;
```

To get an answer for a question, just use the eq method. Just know that it is 0 based so the answer to question 1 is `eq(0)` and the answer to question 2 is `eq(1)`, etc...

```
var answer = $('.answer').eq(0).html();
```