# AJAX Control with Drag and Drop Cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am looking for an ASP.net AJAX control (Grid or Table) that can drag and drop its cells and order them in a column and row row I want. It is a requirement for my Final Year project and I am struggling for a good solution.

In simpler words it is more like a scheduler kind of control.

I am looking for a control like this for ASP.net project

http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/

Comment: are you looking for ajax control which do the task similar to as you mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, Just edited my question with a expected kind of control that I can use in a ASP.net project

Answer (score 0):

There is no such control in Ajax. you have to use any third party control or use Javascript or Jquery to make your own. following link will help you out to achieve this:

[Drag and Drop table cells](http://forums.asp.net/t/1296647.aspx)

[Jquery drag and drop with Table Cells and getting their position to save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613537/jquery-drag-and-drop-with-table-cells-and-getting-their-position-to-save)